# Сравнение чисел в процентном соотношении в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Есть данные `float`:

```
a = 202.7
b = 888435.8
```

И такое условие задачи:

> Если a НЕ БОЛЬШЕ b на 50%
>
> и НЕ МЕНЬШЕ 50%

:присваиваем значение 1.
Каким образом можно реализовать код с таким условием не используя библиотек Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вариант устроит?

```
def check(a,b):
    res=int(abs(a-b) <= max(a,b)/2) #либо просто res=int(abs(a-b) <= b/2)
                                       #если вы уверены, что b - большее
    return res

print(check(202.7, 888435.8)) #0
print(check(7.7, 10.0))       #1
print(check(10, 7.5))         #1
print(check(800.0, 12))       #0
```

**UPDATE** (после уточнений автора вопроса):
Общая логика решения с использованием условных операторов такова:

```
nums=[10, 2.5]
if (min(nums)/max(nums))*100 >= 50:
    print(1) #разница "укладывается" в 50%
elif (min(nums)/max(nums))*100 >= 25:
    print(2) #разница "укладывается" в 25%
else:
    print(3) #разница не "укладывается" ни в 50%, ни в 25%
```

Comment: Лишние круглые скобки `int(abs(a-b) <= max(a,b)/2)` :)

Comment: @gil9red справедливо. исправил

Comment: b не обязательно должно быть большим числом.Алгоритм должен учитывать и это условие.Но спасибо!

Comment: ну вот этот алгоритм и учитывает (там где `max`). а код в комментарии - не учитывает

Comment: Мне нужно сравнить два значения друг с другом.Если а не больше b на 50%  и не меньше 50%,тогда присвоить значение 1,если же нет-тогда не делать ничего.В вашей функции нет операторов ветвления `if`, логического оператора `and`...`pass`.Или же моя логика работает не в верном направлении?

Comment: @SinCap этих операторов нет, потому что для решения вашей задачи в том виде, в каком вы ее представили, они не нужны. Если же от вас требуется по условиям задачи использовать логические операторы, то укажите это в вопросе.

Comment: @ strawdog на самом деле в моей задаче целых 5 условий:когда а меньше b на 100% и более; а больше b на 50% и не больше 100% и т.д.И каждому результату необходимо присвоить свой идентификатор.Условие такое написал лишь для того,чтобы понять логику выполнения задачи.:)